# Fabric js image filter

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way to implement image filters to work like "text object editor" in fabric js? So, when I activate image object...image filters are shown and changes are applied on active object. And when I deactivate object...filters will dissapear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you need :)

Tell me if you need detailed explanation... I'm too stupid for this text editor on stackoverflow :(

```
//check jsfiddle :)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f6P3R/